# Pass an object from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a little problem, I need to give an object at JS when clicked on a button, but I don't know how to do it.

Here is my code php

```
 echo '<script>';
    echo 'var monObjet = "'.json_encode($product).'";';
     echo '<script>';
<button type="button" onclick="ShowModal(monObjet)" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" >Open Modal</button>';
```

and this is my code JS

```
function ShowModal(monObjet){

    var monObjet = monObjet;
    alert(monObjet);

    $('#myModal').appendTo("body").modal("show");

   // $('#NomProduit').text(monObjet);




};
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you want to actually `echo` the button?

Comment: Could you be more precise please? You want to pass an object to JavaScript after you press the Button. Is the Object rendered from PHP and then passed to JS Script for the Button or is it rendered the moment you press the button? However your end scripttag seems broken too it should be '</script>'.  Are there any errors like type errors etc.? There are quotes around your Object too, which make JS think that your object is a string.

Comment: [mcve], please.  jsfiddle.net is one convenient way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo '<script>';
echo 'var monObjet = '.json_encode($product).';';
echo '</script>';
<button type="button" onclick="ShowModal(monObjet)" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" >Open Modal</button>';
```

**Edit:**
You had quotes around the json_encode() part, so JS thought it was a string, not an object.

Comment: More than _try this_ needed so they can tell what the issue is.

Comment: please change '<script>' into '</script>' to make it right.

Comment: @Megajin changed, though it was not the issue causing problems, imho

Comment: @AbraCadaver I don't think he meant to write PHP in plain HTML, this just looks like a dummy code to demonstrate the problem. But of course, that wouldn't work like this, I just think that he would realize it quite simply, because the PHP code would just appear on the page

Comment: @JanKvoch it was not causing the problem, it was just for the rightness of the code style.